# Display first input (radio) opened (checked)

Tags: javascript, input, checked

I am having problems to display only the first input checked.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7jvQX/2/)

The problem there is that is a list created by a PHP, so I just have to add JS to call the function `checked="true"` on the first one, I can't modify them by HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('.nav-dropdown input[type=radio]:first').prop('checked', true);
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7jvQX/4/)</kbd>**

Comment: Seems like work perfectly. I'll check it out in few hours with my iPad, since 'checked="true"' is the only way to make the accordion work. I'll reply asap

Comment: Hey @Pilot . Works perfectly on iPad! Thanks for your time. Xavi Alsina